# Polymer expressions and filters in polymer 1.0

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

How can I use expressions and filters in polymer 1.0?

How could I make this code snippet work?

```
<template>
  1 + 1: <span>{{ 1+1 }}</span>
</template>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Modify html like this:

```
1 + 1: <span>{{sum(1, 1)}}</span>
```

And add this function to Polymer script:

```
sum: function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Currently there’s no general support for expressions in binding annotations. ([source](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#expressions-in-binding-annotations))

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that'd result such a bloat that I am not willing to have. E.g. for a simple loop, I don't want to have a script tag; But even if I have a script tag somewhere, the code gets spread all over the place, instead of a simple in-line expression. E.g. how would you solve [iterating over an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30781500) in a clean way?

Comment: Where should I put the sum function, if I have an expression in my index file ?

Comment: If you provide the iteration example, we might be able to help you over there ;)