# Displaying item content without computed function

Tags: html, polymer, web-component, polymer-1.0

Inside a polymer 1.0 custom element, I would like to iterate over an array an display its items with their content.
All I get is an `[object Object]` tag, without displaying its content.

Is possible to achieve it **without a computed function** -[like in this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30781500/how-can-i-iterate-over-a-js-objects-key-values-in-polymer-1-0)-  iterating every item property and returning it as string?

My list iteration looks like:

```html
<h4>My items:</h4>
<ol>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}">
      <li>{{item}}</li>
    </template>
</ol>
```

I did [a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y0j55c?p=preview) where you can reproduce it.

I saw there's an [open issue](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-expressions/issues/11) referencing this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simple display data of javascript object. You have to do some transform/map its values to some text and/or element maybe.

See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hP34yZc16a7SpDGnaOlp?p=preview) for a little snippet.

```
myData.forEach(function(i) {
        htmlResult.push('Item id:' + i.id);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display the id by

```
<li>{{item.id}}</li>
```

[check the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/X0SBduQ3kGUlayXHteWI?p=preview)

But that is not the requirement. I think Mario is asking for the entire object to come as string.