# template dom-repeat for an Object?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, dart-polymer

I was looking at `dom-repeat`ers with the template tag.  So i was going to walk an array.  I wanted to then walk the properties of the object itself.

I didnt see anything online though.  I was thinking of something like

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}" as="row">
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{row}}" as="prop">
    <div>{{prop}}</div>
  </template>
</tempalate>
```

but the console throws one of those terrible stack traces about null not having the method "_badUpgrade".  Maybe there is better documentation for 1.0 Polymer as to repeating over a dynamic object?

My end state is to create a datagrid allowing dynamic headers and dynamic data....   so the keys of the headers have to be a subset of the data properties so the correct items are assigned under the correct columns etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use dom-repeat with objects instead of arrays in Polymer 1.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30781500/how-to-use-dom-repeat-with-objects-instead-of-arrays-in-polymer-1-0)

Comment: Is the `as="dom-repeat"` valid, shouldn't it be `is`? `as` is the current item in the array or?

Comment: You are correct, It  seemed to be a mistype on my posts end.  I think the issue right now that I have is that i am trying to use polymer dart so the Answer proposed is not correct.  The row is being populated by doing a clear("colKeyData"); addAll("colKeyData", myList);  but doesnt seem to understand what myList is.