# I cannot print the id from an json response with iron-ajax polymer

Tags: json, polymer

I want to print the id from this json response using iron-ajax:

```
{"calinzabalt":{"id":22309843,"name":"calin zabalt","profileIconId":7,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1467295590000}}
```

Using this line of code:

```
 <iron-ajax auto
url="https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/calin%20zabalt?api_key=3012a279-b76c-4df2-b522-2198a0cbe7cc"
handle-as="json"
last-response="{{response}}"></iron-ajax>
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{response}}" >
<p>[[item.id]]</p>
</template>
</template>
```

And this is the message i get from chrome:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use dom-repeat with objects instead of arrays in Polymer 1.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30781500/how-to-use-dom-repeat-with-objects-instead-of-arrays-in-polymer-1-0)

Comment: Not really, this is using iron-ajax.

Comment: The problem is still that you can't use `dom-repeat` with objects, only with arrays. If you convert your object to an array, as it is done in the linked answer, it should work.

Comment: i have no idea how to make this work with the response i get from the api

Comment: you can use {{response.calinzabalt.id}} no need for `dom-repeat`

Comment: thank you, it works now.