# Populate cells without knowing the data key

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, polymer, key-value

My data is an array of objects with key-value pairs.  I'm trying to populate a table with the data in a polymer component.  If I use the key explicitly, it works.  Here is an example with "FacilityId":

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{columns}}">
            <th>{{item}}</th>
        </template>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">
            <tr>
                <td>{{item.FacilityId}}</td>
            </tr>
        </template>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However, as you can see from the dynamically generated columns, I don't always know what the keys will be named.  I tried using `{{item[0]}}` but that doesn't work, and even if it did I won't know how many there will be.  I also tried using a nested template but I couldn't figure it out.

Here is what my data looks like (again, the number and names of fields could vary though):

[image]

Comment: Misread your question, Your `FaciltyId`, `LastMessage` and `SourceConfigName` will stay as is right?, I mean only their respective values will be coming as dynamic right?

Comment: No, the column names and count might change.  This is a reusable Polymer component

Comment: Can you please check the answer given by `Scott Miles` here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30781500/how-to-use-dom-repeat-with-objects-instead-of-arrays-in-polymer-1-0

Comment: definitely needs remapping and flattening, just as @DavidR said

Comment: I had to adjust for the array of objects but I got it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer referenced by @David R, this works:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{columns}}">
            <th>{{item}}</th>
        </template>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">
            <tr>
                <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{_toArray(item)}}">
                    <td>{{item.value}}</td>
                </template>
            </tr>
        </template>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And the custom function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30794220/736893:

```
Polymer({
    is: 'widget-table',
    properties: {
        data: {
            type: Array,
            value: function() {return []}
        }
    },
    _toArray: function(obj) {
        return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
            return {
                name: key,
                value: obj[key]
            };
        });
    }
});
```