# Polymerfire dom-repeat with Firebase objects

Tags: firebase, polymer, firebase-realtime-database, polymerfire

I want to be able to show a list of all the `FirstName` and `ZipCodes`. My data looks as follows:

```
/user
|
|__INAxzxWKQrSAfA7tapV0c08YvfJ3
|   |____FirstName:"James"
|   |____ZipCode:"90210"
|
|__ANAczxWKQrEAfA7tapV0c08YvfX6
    |____FirstName:"Simon"
    |____ZipCode:"40213"
```

and Polymerfire's firebase document looks like this

```
<firebase-document
    app-name="contacts"
    path="/user"
    data="{{allUsers}}">
</firebase-document>
```

And my dom repeat is like

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{_makeArray(allUsers)}}">
    <div class="profile card">
        {{item.FirstName}} 
    </div>
</template>
```

I added the function

```
_makeArray: function(items) {
  return Object.keys(items).map(function (key) {items[key]});
}
```

There are no errors but I also get nothing to the DOM

Answer (score 1):

just use firebase-query instead of firebase-document.  you'll get an array back.

```
<firebase-query
  app-name="contacts"
  path="/user"
  data="{{allUsers}}">
</firebase-query>

<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{allUsers)}}">
  <div class="profile card">
    {{item.FirstName}} 
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

dom-repeat takes an array as the items property. You can do something like this:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[makeArray(allUsers)]]">

...

makeArray: function(items) {
  return Object.keys(items).map(function (key) {items[key]});
}
```

Comment: I tried adding in the code, I have edited the above to reflect the changes but I am getting nothing to the DOM

Comment: When I console.log this.allUsers I get the object so I know I'm getting data from firebase

Comment: Does the new function get called? It should be returning an array of the users.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the return:

```
_makeArray: function(items) {
  return Object.keys(items).map(function (key) { return items[key]; });
}
```

Its works fine with me data are displayed just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Better implementation (also includes the name of the key if required) can be found here:

[How to use dom-repeat with objects instead of arrays in Polymer 1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30794220/4178195)

Also an implementation for two way binding:

[Two way binding for Firebase arrays in dom-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37015188/4178195)

Hope this gets implemented in Polymer 2.0, as Firebase is being advertised but then there are problems with using best practice Polymer and best practice Firebase together.

Answer (score 0):

Use `firebase-query` to return an array of object that you can pass to `dom-repeate`.

```
  <firebase-query
   path="/user"
   data="{{allUsers}}"
   </firebase-query>
```

The `dom-repeat`

add attribute `as="data"`
add property `data.$key`

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{_makeArray(allUsers)}}" as="data">
    <div class="profile card">
        {{data.$key}} 
        {{data.FirstName}} 
    </div>
</template>
```