# Firebase Push ID and Polymer dom-repeat - How to keep two way data binding to sub-properties?

Tags: object, firebase, data-binding, polymer, polymerfire

I am using Firebase and Polymer in the following set-up:

**Firebase-Data**

As you can see, there are several users with their user-id and below a list card-sets. This is basically an array, but stored as object as I want to use `firebase push id` as this might become collaborative.
[image]

**Polymer Code**

With Polymer I am using dom-repeat to iterate over the items (wich worked great as long as I was using still arrays.

```
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{dataCardSet.card-items}}">
       <el-card-editor card-item="{{item}}"></el-card-editor>
    </template>
```

**Problem**

As known, `dom-repeat` needs an Array, but Firebase gives me an Object as I am using the push-ids. Using an Array and store it to Firebase it not an option (e.g. [0: abc, 1: def]).
Also, I **need to keep two-way data-binding**

**Tried solutions**

(1) [One way data binding - Alternative 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40201105/polymerfire-dom-repeat-with-firebase-objects)

(2) [One way data binding - Alternative 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30781500/how-to-use-dom-repeat-with-objects-instead-of-arrays-in-polymer-1-0/30794220#30794220)

(3) [Two way data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30781500/how-to-use-dom-repeat-with-objects-instead-of-arrays-in-polymer-1-0/37015188#37015188)

As said, (1) and (2) are no options. (3) is actually working, but using this solutions, if I update only one sub-property, it updates all sub-properties in the object. This forces dom-repeat to re-initialize the elements. I am using a `<paper-input>` element and thus, it loses its focus after pressing one key.

(4) Also using (1) oder (2) and then binding manually to the sub-properties is not possible, as there is no way to use binding using a dynamic index (e.g. {{dataCardSet.card-items.index}}

(5) I also tried to use `array-selector` within the `dom-repeat`, having the same issue, that I cannot create data-binding dynamically.

**Support needed**

I need a way to keep two-way data binding keeping dom-repeat and using push-IDs.
I am actually surprised and disappointed, as Firebase is advertised but then not working with Polymer framework as a standard.

Also this [Polycast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1f_Tj_JnStA&t=1055s) by Rob Dodson with the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/polymerlabs/todo-list) gives the impression that this would be easily working, but looking at the code, it is using an array and push-IDs as shown in the video.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved the issue in a similar project.

Control the array with `firebase-query`

Control the object with `firebase-document`

**Sample Code**

Inside the `template is="dom-repeat"`, use the attribute `as="item"`to bind to the value of `item.$key`. Add `path="{{item.$key}}` to the `el-card-editor element`.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{dataCardSet.card-items}}" as="item">
 <el-card-editor card-item="{{item}}" path="{{item.$key}}></el-card-editor>
</template>
```

`el-card-editor` element using the value from `{{item.$key}}` construct the path to the object for the element `firebase-document`.

path sample: users/user.uid/card-sets/card-sets.key/card-items/card-items.id

```
<firebase-document path="/build the path here" data="data" ></firebase-document>
<div class="card">
  <h1>{{data.title}}</h1>
  <paper-input label="item" value="{{data.item}}"></paper-input>
</div>
```

**About the Polymer Team**

Let's not forget that they are a small team working really hard to publish polymer 2.0 with new demo and tutorials. It should all be available during the first quarter of 2017.

Comment: Thanks Joel. Didn't know about the size of Polymer team, thanks for the info :) About your solution: If I understand your solution correct, I would load several times from Firebase (for each card), as `firebase-document`is inside `el-card-editor`, correct? I had a similar approach before and it was very slow in performance. Imagine a set of 100 cards, that would mean 100 requests to Firebase.

Comment: I have the same design in my project, loading the array and list take 18ms, you can lazy load the results in batch for a large list. (Infinite Scroll). Firebase recommend to avoid nesting data for optimal performance, take a look at their website they have great tutorial over there.